# Small api on node.js

Tags: node.js

maybe someone have example for creating small API on node.js

Example, i have function this function will return string 
I need call this string from postman or inside any another project with http.
What better for create this API? 
Maybe someone know good guide? I worked before with node.js only like web-server

Comment: Have you tried express.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is best practice that building API's in nodejs with express.Here is a code in which function returns a string. You need to export it. And require the file that contains exported value in your project file with the file path. Here is my function code where I am returning a string value. `func.js`

```
var string;
function myfunc(param,callback){
    var str="hello";
    callback(null,str);
    }
myfunc('aaa',function(err,result){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    else{
        exports.string=result;

    }
});
```

Here is my routes file and here I am calling the string from `func.js` and I named this file as  `str.js`

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var main = require('./func.js');//path of file

var org = main.string;

var app = express();

app.get('/str',function(req,res){
console.log(org);
res.send(org);
});

app.listen(3000,function(){
console.log("Server listening on 3000");
});
```

Run the code as `node str.js` and in postman run the url as `http://localhost:3000/str` and you can see the returned string in both response and in terminal.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thank you very much) This help a lot

Answer (score 0):

This [tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-api-using-node-and-express-4) shows you how to build an API in Node.js with Express.

EDIT: You can skip the database part if you don't need it.